# Should I use Multiple RegularExpression attributes

Tags: c#

**Update 8:**
The question has a new title ,hopefully it will help other avoid time consuming  bugs...

I have the following code:
(You need a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var itemModelX = new MyModel() { Name = "1<d" };

            var contextX = new ValidationContext(itemModelX, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var resultsX = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var isValidX = Validator.TryValidateObject(itemModelX, contextX, resultsX, true);

            if (isValidX)
                Console.WriteLine("Should not see this");

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        [MultipleRegExAttribute2(@"[^?.]{1,100}$")]
        [MultipleRegExAttribute2(@"^((?![><&])[\s\S])*$")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field | System.AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class MultipleRegExAttribute2 : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public MultipleRegExAttribute2(string pattern) : base(pattern) { }
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 5 the output is

> "Should not see this"
>   "Finished"

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 1 the output is

> "Finished"

Roslyn is the correct one,the question is why 2013 is not working?
I'm pretty sure is that was working in 2013 also,don't know when it broke,I don't have a previous update to test it...
I'm using .NET 4.5.1

**Update 1**
Even if I remove the reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and add the code to my project (You can find the code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)) I get different outputs.

**Update 2**
Forgot to say that it only happens if I have 2 MultipleRegExAttributes ,if I remove the first one it works as expected

**Update 3**
I've uploaded an entire solution [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C905464030322011!291332&authkey=!ADom0R0NMPqVUow&ithint=file%2Czip)

**Update 4**
I check the generated IL for both assemblies but the only difference I see is the initialization of a few locals

*VS2015*

```
.locals init (
    [0] class [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations]System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext contextX,
    [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations]System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> resultsX             )
```

VS2013

```
.locals init (
    [0] class ConsoleApp.MyModel itemModelX,
    [1] class [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations]System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext contextX,
            [2] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations]System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> resultsX,
            [3] bool isValidX,
            [4] class ConsoleApp.MyModel '<>g__initLocal0'
        )
```

**Update 5**
Almost there...

- VS2015 only checks the second attribute(Which happens to be the one I
  care about in the case)
- VS2013 only checks the first argument...

**Update 6**
After many many hours...
 - It seems there always is a problem if I have more than 1 RegularExpressionAttribute
    That could be my mistake because I extend the class and "override" AllowMultiple

2.Why do I get different results when I compile it with VS2015?
   The class that returns the attributes is System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor in method GetAttributes.
    I have to see what is change there...

**Update 7**
It seems that something has change in way PropertyDescriptor/MemberDescriptor returns the Attributes.
In VS2015 it prints the second regex,in VS2013 the first.
So,which of the following is true?

- a)This is an implementation detail and I shouldn't rely on this
- b)This is a bug since it is a breaking change
- c)a and b
- d)other

.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(MyModel))[0];
            var attribute = property.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>();
            foreach (var item in attribute)
                if (item is MultipleRegExAttribute2)
                    Console.WriteLine(((MultipleRegExAttribute2)item).GetPattern());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        [MultipleRegExAttribute2(@"[^?.]{1,100}$")]
        [MultipleRegExAttribute2(@"^((?![><&])[\s\S])*$")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Field | System.AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class MultipleRegExAttribute2 : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {
        public MultipleRegExAttribute2(string pattern) : base(pattern) { }
        public string GetPattern() { return this.Pattern; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have You try testing exe intead of using debug mode in VS?

Comment: Am I crazy?Can anyone else reproduce it?

Comment: @blogprogramisty.net What do you mean "test the exe" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>DO NOT extend RegularExpressionAttribute and set AllowMultiple to true

It will bring you nothing but trouble.</s>    
You can create 2 distinct attributes that inherit from RegularExpressionAttribute.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [MultipleRegExAttribute2(@"[^?.]{1,100}$")]
    [MultipleRegExAttribute3(@"^((?![><&])[\s\S])*$")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class MultipleRegExAttribute2 : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public MultipleRegExAttribute2(string pattern) : base(pattern) { }
}


public class MultipleRegExAttribute3 : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public MultipleRegExAttribute3(string pattern) : base(pattern) { }
}
```

## Update

A friend of mine showed me the root of the problem.
I have to override the TypeId property.
See this question:[Custom validation attribute with multiple instances problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362886/custom-validation-attribute-with-multiple-instances-problem)
and this article :[The Importance of TypeId in ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotations Validation Attributes](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/03/02/the-importance-of-typeid-in-asp.net-mvc-dataannotations-validation-attributes.aspx/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info but as for the two regular expression attributes it does not make sense to me. Use a single regular expression instead.

Comment: @Ares Yes,that's another option but I prefer it this way because I can reuse each attribute on other classes.If I had better names it would have been clearer